Purpose of test set in cross-validation
How does the test set in k-fold cross-validation have any purpose? The most common argument in favor of a test set I can find is to not have any data leakage between training and testing. But you don't have this in cross-validation anyways...?
Each fold during cross-validation, you train and test/validate your data on separate sets with no leakage. Averaging over k individual results still does not result in any leakage (or am I stupid)? Testing the entire result on another, separate set is thus completely useless.
If your data is biased by groups (e.g., different doctors in medical analysis), you can even use grouped cross-validation. If you fear you have overfitting during cross validation and are just "lucky" to get a good result, you can either monitor the variance between each individual fold or - even better - just do a repeated cross-validation and compare results. Anyways, this should happen only on small data samples, where splitting off some additional data only hurts the entire process even more.
So how can a test set ever improve my evaluation of a set of models? How does this ever help me find the best model?
or
Others say it's to only "validate your model once you selected one due to cross-validation". What does this even mean? Either I get a similar result to cross-validation; at this point, including additional data into the cross-validation would just make more robust, or I get a different result and then all I know is that the entire cross-validation process was fraudulent, although at this point once again there are better methods to check for this.
One example that made me read up onto this topic and really start wondering about all the different takes on this (although at this point I'm very certain that it actually is a very bad example of using cross-validation):
The author wanted to compare different models and select the best one. Therefore, he split his data into training and testing sets. He used 10-fold cross-validation to determine the best model, had 2 models with similar quality, and then used the test data to decide between those 2. Is there any reason to ever use this procedure?

If you use cross-validation for model selection (including hyper-parameter tuning) then you may look at hundreds of potential models in order to choose the one which performs best on the various validation folds.
It is precisely this usage of performance on the validation folds to decide your model which risks what you call "data leakage", and means that you may not be able to rely on that to gauge likely performance on as-yet-unseen data.
The single test of your final model on the initially held-out test data is designed to avoid or mitigate this issue.  If the test performs too poorly, then you may decide to start all over again. To do so honestly and to avoid the test stage turning into a further form of validation, you will need new previously-unused test data.
There is no obligation to follow the training-validation-test paradigm, but you should decide this before you start, and for good reasons.  One reason might be that subject-knowledge means you are only considering a single model which does not need tuning, while another might be  you have too little data to hold out a test set, though in either of those two cases you need to recognise you may end up with a poorly performing model.

But CV basically performs multiple tests on yet-unseen data.
Let's hold 10% of our data back as test data bcs it is measured differently. Then performing a 10-fold grouped CV will simply include the last testing step (training the model on all test data and testing it on the test set). But the other 9 folds are more robust and better trained, thus the model selection process is more robust as well.
1/4

To be extra cautious about the whole situation, we do a repeated CV (this time non-grouped to have different validation sets inside the CV) for only our selected model. We now have the results of 10 cases where we trained this model and compared its performance on yet-unseen data (for this model).
2/4

It seems sufficiently unlikely to find a model that can be trained 10 different times and performs on 10 (actually 20) different validation sets, but only for this one set of data. But including any other data would likely show its shortcomings. At this point, it seems more likely that selecting a model on a smaller training set would faultily show a good performance in 1 additional test on 1 additional data set.
3/4

One addition: For extensive hyperparameter tuning on small data sets, i.e., the number of models is of the same magnitude as our training data (or any similar situation), it seems more plausible to find a model that is able to be trained correctly on this one data set but only due to the specifics of this exact set. Then again, more training data makes the process more robust, but simply using repeated CV won't solve the problem, so here I see the point of a test set. But I'm talking about more generic cases where training data is magnitudes larger than models to be tested.
4/4

The test set is to more accurately assess performance. There is some randomness involved in cross validation accuracy. Based on how the cut is made, how exactly the hyperparameters work out, the accuracy can fluctuate a bit. So if you try 50 hyperparameter combinations, you will probably pick a "lucky split" and overestimate real world performance. The test set is to offset this, after picking an approach, you do a final assessment of the performance based on the testset, which should not be far of the result you got from the crossvalidation.

The cut between training and test data is (in most cases) as arbitrary as any cut inside the training set.
Additionally, what excactly does it tell you if your accuracy/any other measure is slightly worse on the test set? And if it is significantly worse, all you know is something went wrong with your CV.
Anyways, for both arguments, doing a repeated CV would give you more robust results (with each individual CV being better). If computational expense is a factor, comparing variance should give a sufficiently good measure in any of those cases without the risk of an (un)lucky test set.

@Linrael You say "if it is significantly worse, all you know is something went wrong with your CV", but without a test set you would not have realised this.  How you separate the test data and create the cross-validation folds also matters: if you are looking at multiple observation for various individuals, there is a distinction between forecasting for the same individuals or forecasting fro new individuals, ans your data splits should reflect this.

Usually a repeated CV shows this.
And to include measurement specific features into your training process there is grouped CV to consider this.

It is a best practice. I have definitely at times ignored this and just relied on CV results, because, indeed, I also believe it is usually fine. There are times when your CV results will however overestimate true performance, when you have little data, lots of hyperparameters. And it is not so easy to know when this starts having an effect.
